# Working with NorthWind database in ASP.NET and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core

`Employee` model class:

[[image: Employee Model class]

Order model class:

[[image: Order Model Class]

Order Details model class:

*(link missing)*

I was trying to write a SQL query to return the name of employee with maximum number of sales in C#.

The database used is the Northwind sample database in which to fetch the required query I had to join the `Employee`, `Order` and `OrderDetails` tables.

I tried doing joining the `Employee` table with `Order` table which in turn was joined to `OrderDetails` table which has quantity column. I thought of grouping by order id and then multiplying the count of each element in the group with quantity, but I am stuck now.

```cs
var a = dbContext.Employees
                 .Include(a => (a.Orders)
                 .GroupBy(a => a.EmployeeId).Count());
```

Comment: Show model classes.

Comment: Not as images, but as text. Images cannot be copied.

Answer (score 0):

```
(from e in Employees
orderby e.Orders.Count() descending
 select $"{e.TitleOfCourtesy} {e.FirstName} {e.LastName} ({e.Title})").Take(1)
```